# Regex expression for the date format

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, date

I need the regex expression that will find/match below formats

**1st July 2018 , July 2nd 2018 , 4th March ,2018** 
(with , and without comma also either dd/mmm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy)
I have below regular expression , that is working fine [here](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx)

The regular expression is

```
(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)[a-z]*?\s+\d{1,2}(?:[a-z]{2})?(?:\s+|,\s*)\d{4}\b
```

But it is not working with my code , I dont know what I am placing wrong ...

My code is

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)[a-z]*?\s+\d{1,2}(?:[a-z]2})?(?:\s+|,\s*)\d{4}\b");
Match match = regex.Match(html);
return match.Value;
```

Also the above expression is responsible for

**January 1st, 2020** But I need also **1st January  2020** ..

Comment: Please remove all spaces in the pattern, and retry.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried after removing space but no luck..

Comment: Please edit the question.

Comment: I edited the question and removed spaces , or you need else editing ? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Note you tested on a Web site where ignore case is on, you did not use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`. [This one](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%29%3f%28%3f%3ajan%7cfeb%7cmar%7capr%7cmay%7cjun%7cjul%7caug%7csep%7coct%7cnov%7cdec%29%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%29%3f%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*%29%3f%5cd%7b4%7d%5cb&i=1st+July+2018+%2c+July+2nd+2018+%2c+4th+March+%2c2018+%28with+%2c+and+without+comma+also+either+dd%2fmmm%2fyyyy+and+mm%2fdd%2fyyyy%29+January+1st%2c+2020+But+I+need+also+1st+January+2020&o=i) can work, but not for `dd/mm/yy`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this ignore case is working , It recognizes January 2nd, 2012
I also have to add rule to recognize 2nd January, 2012 . is that feasible ?

Comment: Sir @WiktorStribiżew can we combine these two rules so we can have all matches

Comment: See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%29%3f%28%3f%3ajan%7cfeb%7cmar%7capr%7cmay%7cjun%7cjul%7caug%7csep%7coct%7cnov%7cdec%29%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%29%3f%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*%29%3f%5cd%7b4%7d%5cb&i=1st+July+2018+%2c+July+2nd+2018+%2c+4th+March+%2c2018+%28with+%2c+and+without+comma+also+either+dd%2fmmm%2fyyyy+and+mm%2fdd%2fyyyy%29+January+1st%2c+2020+But+I+need+also+1st+January+2020%0d%0a2nd+January%2c+2012&o=i).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I have gone through this already..  Its not working for the case of JULY 1ST 2018 .. Can we place a condition where we can get both of these date formats

Comment: It does work for [`JULY 1ST 2018`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%29%3f%28%3f%3ajan%7cfeb%7cmar%7capr%7cmay%7cjun%7cjul%7caug%7csep%7coct%7cnov%7cdec%29%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%29%3f%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*%29%3f%5cd%7b4%7d%5cb&i=1st+July+2018+%2c+July+2nd+2018+%2c+4th+March+%2c2018+%28with+%2c+and+without+comma+also+either+dd%2fmmm%2fyyyy+and+mm%2fdd%2fyyyy%29+January+1st%2c+2020+But+I+need+also+1st+January+2020%0d%0a2nd+January%2c+2012%0d%0aJULY+1ST+2018&o=i).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and for 1ST JULY 2018 as well ??

Comment: I understand it is not very safe, but [this one](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%28%3f%3aof%5cs%2b%29%3f%29%3f%28%3f%3ajan%7cfeb%7cmar%7capr%7cmay%7cjun%7cjul%7caug%7csep%7coct%7cnov%7cdec%29%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5ba-z%5d*%5cs*%29%3f%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*%29%3f%5cd%7b4%7d%5cb&i=1st+July+2018+%2c+July+2nd+2018+%2c+4th+March+%2c2018++January+1st%2c+2020+But+I+need+also+1st+January+2020%0d%0a2nd+January%2c+2012%0d%0aJULY+1ST+2018%0d%0a1ST+JULY+2018%0d%0a1ST+JULY+2018++1STJULY+%2c2018+1ST+++JULY%2c+2018++1ST+of+JULY%2c2018&o=i) matches them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew working very fine thanks sir , Also if I have to change the format of this detected date to specific format 07/01/2018 (in numeric). Is that possible ?

Comment: @JotSingh why use a regex at all? Why not `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` ? If you want it to validate DTO values you can specify the type, format using Data annotation attributes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos will it search for the date of any format as well from the given string ?

Comment: @JotSingh the regex won't parse French or German or Greek month names anyway. The parsing functions can do so though, if you pass the appropriate CultureInfo. `TryParseExact` at least has an overload that allows you to specify *multiple* formats

Comment: @JotSingh btw that regex can't tell between MM/DD and DD/MM. You *can't* distinguish between April 7th and July 4th just by looking at the text, you *have* to know the culture. Why do you want to use that regex though? Whether for parsing or validation there are better ways. Perhaps you should use a date picker on the client so you only get ISO dates on the server

Comment: @I Have paragraph in which date is of format 1st june 2018 I have to detect it and convert to 06/01/2018 . thats all I need

Comment: This is how you can specify what you expect at the input and then output a date time object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Lukos any example code explained will be helpfull

Comment: There are examples at the bottom of the page I linked!

Answer (score 1):

Here is C# function which matched and return result true or false for all formats you mention, you can add more date format in formats array also

```html
    public bool checkIsValidDateTime(string date)
        {
            var formats = new[] { "dd MMMM yyyy", "MMMM dd yyyy", "dd MMMM ,yyyy", "MMMM dd, yyyy", "d MMMM yyyy", "MMMM d yyyy", "d MMMM ,yyyy", "MMMM d, yyyy" };

            DateTime dt;
        
            var replacements = new[]{
             new{Find="st",Replace=""},
             new{Find="nd",Replace=""},
             new{Find="rd",Replace=""},
             new{Find="th",Replace=""}
              };


            foreach (var set in replacements)
            {
                date = date.Replace(set.Find, set.Replace);
              
            }

            bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, formats, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

            return isValid;
        }
        
        // which return true for following formats
        
            string input = "1st July 2018";
            string input2 = "July 2nd 2018";
            string input3 = "3rd March ,2018";
            string input4 = "January 4th, 2020";
            string input5 = "20th January 2020";


     bool isvalid1 = checkIsValidDateTime(input); // result true
     bool isvalid2 = checkIsValidDateTime(input2); // result true
     bool isvalid3 = checkIsValidDateTime(input3); // result true
     bool isvalid4 = checkIsValidDateTime(input4); // result true
     bool isvalid5 = checkIsValidDateTime(input5); // result true
```

Comment: Dude code works very well , I appreciate the code writing style . But I have to  match the date from paragraph that is main stream